# ASP.NET Core as a Windows Service - How to configure endpoints?

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-services

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web application which is hosted as a Windows Service on my machine.

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#configure-endpoints), it says I can "configure the URL and port by setting the ASPNETCORE_URLS environment variable."

Therefore I created the following System environment variable:

Variable: ASPNETCORE_URLS

Value: http://myapp.debug:5100

I tried a few variations of the above URL and port but when I run my ASP.NET Core application from Visual Studio and try to hit the URL nothing happens.

How do I setup my own custom URL for my application? Is there anything else I'm missing?

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseWindowsService()
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
        })
        .UseNLog();
```

Comment: Is DNS properly setup?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit clueless, what would I need to setup for DNS?

Comment: myapp.debug is not a registered domain and therefore does not resolve to the IP of your host where the service is running. You can use http://localhost:5100 as value for ASPNETCORE_URLS to make DNS resolution work locally. For real publishing i wouldn't recommend using a Windows Service. I would recommend IIS or Docker.

Comment: So this is just going to be running locally on a customer's server, but want to it assign it to a custom port and give the URL a different name

Comment: then you should think of registering the domain to ensure that nobody will take it and then create a DNS record pointing to 127.0.0.1 or localhost. You can also create a record at hosts file but its not as secure as owning the domain.